# Change Server 2012 R2 domain name in network section

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, windows, user-management

In the network section of a Windows Server 2012 R2 displays the name of the domain as domain 2. For example: "mydomain.net 2". Ive seen similar problems with wireless profiles and that can be resolved through netsh.exe but cant find an option for AD profiles. How can i reset this to show as "mydomain.net"?

Thank You

Comment: Are you referring to viewing the networks in Network and Sharing Center? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @joeqwerty Yes Networking and Sharing: I tried but unfortunetly I cant add images because I dotn have 10 reputation. It is in the disply area not the actual domain for example i.e. Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center

Comment: does that server is multihomed ?

Comment: I tossed you an upvote towards a screenshot.  In the meantime, maybe you can find some kind of temporary place to stash an image and post a link to it.  Perhaps some kindly person might even embed it for you if you do that.  :)